# What CPAN module to use for nonblocking file locking with Perl

Tags: perl, cpan, nonblocking, file-locking

I want to make sure only one process at a time runs.  So I want to make sure jobB doesn't run unless jobA is not running.

It would be great if it had some ability to retry the lock so I don't have to code that.  Something vaguely like this:

```
LockFileModule->lock(
    lockfile           => '/fabulous/pants',
    retries            => 12,
    timeout            => 25,
    timebetweenretries => 30,
) or die "the other job is still running";
```

Whats the best way to do this in Perl?  I'm hoping there is a good CPAN module for this.

Comment: Yes its simple and works great.  But it doesn't retry the lock.  Probably I should suck it up and write the four lines of code to do the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
unless (flock(DATA, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB)) {
    $logger->info("$0 is already running. Exiting.\n" );
    exit(1);
} else {
    $logger->info("$0 not already running, so starting instance now." );
}

__DATA__
Do not delete this. Used for flock code above
```

This will lock the **DATA** section of the program itself. I use this technique, and it works very well.

You can expand it to enable retries pretty easily.

Comment: NFS depends on the implementation of NFS. In general, yes.